# How to highlight matched part of a string in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, highlighting

This is my current function in php:

```
function highlight_keywords($keyword, $string) {
    return preg_replace("/\p{L}*?".preg_quote($keyword)."\p{L}*/ui", "<span class=\"h\">$0</span>", $string);
}
```

The css class:

```
span.h {
    font-weight: 700;
    color: @color_action;
}
```

Example:

```
echo highlight_keywords('anto', 'Andres Santos');
```

The problem is that the result is:

```
Andres <span class="h">Santos</span>
```

...and it should be:

```
Andres S<span class="h">anto</span>s
```

Comment: Why do you have the \p{L}*? part of the pattern?  Why not just `return preg_replace("/".preg_quote($keyword)."/ui", "<span class=\"h\">$0</span>", $string);`

Comment: @BrandonHorsley you're right. Your answer is even simpler than the first response below.

Comment: There's no need to use a regex to match a static value. Use `return str_replace($keyword, '<span class="h">' . $keyword . '</span>', $string);`

Comment: @chris85 is correct, str_ireplace if you need case insensitive.

Comment: I might be wrong, but str_replace does not always play nice when returning special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use capture groups:

```
function highlight_keywords($keyword, $string) {
    return preg_replace("/(\p{L}*?)(".preg_quote($keyword).")(\p{L}*)/ui", "$1<span class=\"h\">$2</span>$3", $string);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @chris85 in his comment. There is no reason for you to use regex for this task.

Just replace the literal string with the tag-wrapped literal string.

```
return str_replace($keyword, '<span class="h">' . $keyword . '</span>', $string);
```

If you need case-insensitive support, then I agree with @BrandoneHorsley that `str_ireplace()` will suffice.

```
return str_ireplace($keyword, '<span class="h">' . $keyword . '</span>', $string);
```

As for your concern regarding special characters, our beloved @deceze [has this to say/demonstrate as the highest voted comment in the php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php#:%7E:text=Please%20note,%20multibyte%20strings):

> Please note that all the discussion about mb_str_replace in the
> comments is pretty pointless. str_replace works just fine with
> multibyte strings